# Check for Admin privilege in Blogger

Tags: blogger, blogspot

Is there a way to check whether a user is an administrator or not? Something like `<b:if cond='data:post.admin'>`. I would like to hide the widget edit icon to regular users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to check user privilege in blogger than using blogger auto injected stylesheet `authorization.css` which generates a style to display class `.blog-admin` which was hidden in template for all users by default, this generated style override the default style in template when user is admin.

**example:**

in blog

[image]

for regular user it generates :

[image]

for admin user it generates :

[image]

The new blogger templates don't inject `authorization.css` stylesheet automatically anymore, so you have to add it manually if you're using a new blogger template.

The old blogger templates inject `authorization.css` stylesheet but in most of templates developers disabling it to avoid auto injected stylesheet `bundle.css` too.

So now, you have to detect the version of your template and check if `authorization.css` provided or disabled in first.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the content by using following condition:

```
data:cb.level.author != &quot;Anonymous&quot;
```

Comment: or use this condition  data:cb.level.author

Comment: Please don't promote your own blog unless it directly solves the OP's problem.